# Extracting the edges of odd degree vertices in a graph

Tags: c++, matrix, graph-theory

I have a graph as follows, represented by an adjacency matrix `MyCustomVector<MyCustomVector<int>> graph`:

```
0       1       2       3       4       5       6       7       8       9       10      11      12      13      14      15

1       0       1       1       INF     INF     INF     INF     INF     INF     INF     INF     INF     INF     INF     INF
2       1       0       1       1       1       INF     INF     INF     INF     INF     INF     INF     INF     INF     INF
3       1       1       0       INF     INF     1       INF     INF     INF     INF     INF     INF     INF     INF     INF
4       INF     1       INF     0       1       INF     INF     INF     1       INF     INF     INF     INF     INF     INF
5       INF     1       INF     1       0       1       INF     INF     INF     1       1       INF     INF     INF     INF
6       INF     INF     1       INF     1       0       1       INF     1       1       INF     1       INF     INF     INF
7       INF     INF     INF     INF     INF     1       0       1       INF     INF     INF     INF     1       1       1
8       INF     INF     INF     INF     INF     INF     1       0       INF     INF     INF     INF     INF     INF     1
9       INF     INF     INF     1       INF     1       INF     INF     0       INF     INF     INF     INF     INF     INF
10      INF     INF     INF     INF     1       1       INF     INF     INF     0       INF     INF     INF     INF     INF
11      INF     INF     INF     INF     1       INF     INF     INF     INF     INF     0       1       INF     INF     INF
12      INF     INF     INF     INF     INF     1       INF     INF     INF     INF     1       0       INF     INF     INF
13      INF     INF     INF     INF     INF     INF     1       INF     INF     INF     INF     INF     0       1       INF
14      INF     INF     INF     INF     INF     INF     1       INF     INF     INF     INF     INF     1       0       1
15      INF     INF     INF     INF     INF     INF     1       1       INF     INF     INF     INF     INF     1       0
```

The leftmost and topmost column and row just represent the # node. I thought it was easier to see. All edges are undirected and have a weight of one. `INF` indicates that there node A and node B do not share a singular edge.

I can calculate all of the odd degree vertices, which are `{ 3 4 5 7 14 15 }` and they are contained in a vector that I have `MyCustomVector<int> oddVertices`. What I want to do is build a subgraph of this graph with only these vertices and their edges, so something like this.

```
0       3       4       5       7       14       15   
3       0       INF     INF     INF     INF      INF
4       INF     0       1       INF     INF      INF
5       INF     1       0       INF     INF      INF
7       INF     INF     INF     0       1        1  
14      INF     INF     INF     1       0        1                                             
15      INF     INF     INF     1       1        0
```

So that I can run the Floyd Warshall Algorithm on this graph and get

```
0       3       4       5       7       14       15   
3       0       2       2       2       3        3
4       2       0       1       3       4        4
5       2       1       0       2       1        1
7       2       3       2       0       1        1  
14      3       4       3       1       0        1                                             
15      3       4       3       1       1        0
```

I am having trouble managing the adjacency matrix and grabbing the columns that I need. Essentially what I want to do is

1. Iterate through the graph
2. Notice that the node we are currently on is contained in `oddVertices`
3. Add the other nodes that are contained in `oddVertices`.

I cannot use any other data structure than `MyCustomVector`, and it only has basic functionality like `[]`, `size()`, `pop_back()` and `push_back()`.

Comment: what are the node and edges number in graph?

Comment: @arbitrary_A my graph is just dealing with nodes labelled from {1, ..., n}. in this case, n = 15. a '1' at a certain [i][j] indicates a shared edge between nodes i and j, or INF otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply extract the rows and columns corresponding to the subset of indices:

```cpp
using std::vector;

/*
** input:
**   adjacency list                adj
**   subset of node indices        v
** output:
**   adj list of induced subgraph  subadj
*/
vector<vector<int>> get_subgraph(vector<vector<int>> const &adj, vector<int> const &v)
{
    vector<vector<int>> subadj(v.length(), vector<int>(v.length()));
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i)
        for (unsigned int j = 0; j < v.size(); ++j)
        {
            subadj[i][j] = adj[v[i]][v[j]];
        }
    return subadj;
}
```